# mysql stored procedure SELECT * into out parameter not working

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

SQL

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `my_sp`(
  IN in_var VARCHAR(32),
  OUT out_var VARCHAR(255)
)
BEGIN

  /*This work OK*/  
  SELECT my_column INTO out_var FROM my_table WHERE my_column = in_var LIMIT 1;

  /*This not work*/
  SELECT * INTO out_var FROM my_table WHERE my_column = in_var LIMIT 1;

END;
```

PHP

```
$dbh = new PDO( $connection_params );
$sql = "CALL my_sp( :in_var , @outvar )";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare( $sql );
$stmt->execute( array( ':in_var' => $_POST['in_var'] ) );

$sql = "SELECT @outvar";
$query = $dbh->query( $sql );
$result = $query->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
```

When I try 'SELECT * ...' then in php var_dump($stmt) return false;

I'm starting with MySQL and I do not know if you can not do this type of query (SELECT *) in stored procedures, or it's something else?

Comment: Well, multiple columns does not equal one variable.  This error makes total sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `out_var` declaration and you will be able to fetch all the columns:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `my_sp`(
    IN in_var VARCHAR(32)
)
BEGIN

  SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_column = in_var LIMIT 1;

END;
```

Or you can declare a variable for each column.

Comment: This was what I was looking for. When I tried it, I realized that it is not necessary to remove the declared variables and only to delete the INTO out_var statement from the query. In this way the same SP can be used in several modes  with conditions IF etc.